# Access a web-application using HTTPS over Mule 3

Tags: mule

I have deployed Mule as a web-application. I use Mule to access my webservices over HTTPS. For which I have HTTPS implemented on Mule, which works fine.

Now, I want to integrate another Web-Application instead of a webservice and want to use the same HTTPS implemented on Mule instead of implementing SSL again on my Weblogic server. But when I try the URL gets redirected to my outbound HTTP URL though my inbound endpoint is HTTPS.

Comment: Can you show your xml config? What is your https:outbound-endpoint set to?

Comment: Also what version of Mule precisely?